# Curl and Git Bast POST request

Tags: curl, git-bash

I'm doind a POST Resquest in Curl with GIT BASH. I'm new to this type of request. What I'm doing wrong here? Thanks for the suggestions, this is the first I'm trying this type of request which I don't completely understand. This is a tutorial I'm following : https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/topics/request-submit.html .

Any other solutions?

This is my code:

Curl and Git Bast POST request

```
$ curl https://batch.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/jobs
mailto={simere.com}
&gen=8
&header=true
&indelim=%7C
&outdelim=%7C
&outcols=displayLatitude,displayLongitude,locationLabel,
houseNumber,street,district,city,postalCode,
county,state,country
&outputCombined=false
&app_code={ OBasqavTxfN1}
&app_id={RfsseIcVfmV7w}
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   286  100   286    0     0    295      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   295{"error":"Bad Request","error_description":"The r                equest is missing the app_id and app_code parameters. They must both be passed as query parameters. If you do not have app_id a                nd app_code, please obtain them through your customer representative or at http://developer.here.com/myapps."}

renau@DESKTOP-2EC3B6J MINGW64 ~
$ ?action=run
bash: ?action=run: command not found

renau@DESKTOP-2EC3B6J MINGW64 ~
$ mailto={simon.re.com}

renau@DESKTOP-2EC3B6J MINGW64 ~
$ &gen=8
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'

renau@DESKTOP-2EC3B6J MINGW64 ~
$ &header=true
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'

renau@DESKTOP-2EC3B6J MINGW64 ~
$ &indelim=%7C
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'

renau@DESKTOP-2EC3B6J MINGW64 ~
$ &outdelim=%7C
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'

renau@DESKTOP-2EC3B6J MINGW64 ~
$ &outcols=displayLatitude,displayLongitude,locationLabel,
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'

renau@DESKTOP-2EC3B6J MINGW64 ~
$ houseNumber,street,district,city,postalCode,
bash: houseNumber,street,district,city,postalCode,: command not found

renau@DESKTOP-2EC3B6J MINGW64 ~
$ county,state,country
bash: county,state,country: command not found

renau@DESKTOP-2EC3B6J MINGW64 ~
$ &outputCombined=false
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'

renau@DESKTOP-2EC3B6J MINGW64 ~
$ &app_code={ OBascvTxfN1}
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'

renau@DESKTOP-2EC3B6J MINGW64 ~
$ &app_id={RfsseIQvcVfmV7w}
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the page "[Tools](https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/topics/tools.html)":

> When submitting a job using "`wget`" and "`cURL`", check field names (e.g., `&outCols=recId,…`) and field delimiter in the request for both the input and the output.
>   `wget` and `cURL` will return a "`400 Bad Request`" response in case there is a mistype or when the delimiter does not match the delimiter in the input file.
>   Both `wget` and `cURL` need a content type to be specified in the header.
>   Uploading compressed address data is currently not supported
>
> If you use `cURL`, be sure to add the following header
>
> ```
> Content-Type: text/plain
> ```
>
> and submit the payload using the `--data-binary` parameter.

Example:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain" --data-binary @addresses.txt
  "https://batch.geocoder.cit.api.here.com
/6.2/jobs?
  &app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}
  &app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}
  &action=run
  &header=true
  &inDelim=;
  &outDelim=,
  &outCols=recId,latitude,longitude,locationLabel
  &mailto={YOUR_EMAIL}
  &outputcombined=true
  &language=de-DE"
```

Comment: I'm new to that and I'm trying to understand how i can use the original format. If I want to keep the original format in what tools, softwares i will run my http request without using wget or curl? whats the options?

Comment: "without using wget or curl?" your question was *specifically* about curl: that is what my answer addresses.

Comment: Yes, correct. I would also like to know in ''what'' I can code this Post request in the original format?

Comment: @Simre That command can be used in a shell, or in a script executed in a shell.